# How to add the Gerrit Change-ID in Visual Studio Code commit

Tags: visual-studio-code, gerrit

In our project Change-id is mandatory for commits, but I did not found how to add it in Visual Studio Code.

I downloaded the "Gerrit" plug-in, but even so I did not fond a way to add the Change-ID

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the "commit-msg" hook in the ".git" directory of your local repository.

See more details in the Gerrit documentation [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/user-changeid.html).

Basically you need to go (cd) to your local repository and execute the following command:

```
gitdir=$(git rev-parse --git-dir); curl --create-dirs -Lo ${gitdir}/hooks/commit-msg https://GERRIT-SERVER/tools/hooks/commit-msg; chmod u+x ${gitdir}/hooks/commit-msg
```

After that, every time you create a new commit or change (--amend) an old one, the Change-Id will be automatically added.